# Фоновые задачи ASP.NET

Tags: c#

Создаю бота для ВК используя Callback API. Всю основу уже сделал, есть БД, использую миграции. Как мне, на пример, каждые 10 секунд обновлять переменную в БД? Уже все обыскал, не могу найти. Прошу, пожалуйста, дать пример и по возможности объяснить!

Comment: Ну а что вы пробовали то?

Comment: Hangfire, но не могу понять куда код пихать в колбэке

Comment: А зачем вам для Callback API менять что то каждые 10 сек.? Вопрос чисто ради любопытства...

Comment: Ну вот предположим я делаю игрового бота. Через какое-то определенное время (пусть будет 1 час) в базе данных должен меняться баланс людей у которых есть некий бизнес.

Comment: Не надо ничего обновлять ни раз в 10 секунд, ни раз в час. Просто когда происходит некое событие, например, покупка человеком в игре некоего завода, заносите в БД время события. Потом, когда происходит следующее событие, например, человек проверяет баланс, рассчитываете сумму доходов/расходов за прошедший период времени.

Comment: Отличная идея! Спасибо!